# Design a Counter With an Arbitrary Sequence

Tags: flipflop, counter

I'm trying to design an asynchronous counter with JK flip- flops, with an arbitrary sequence.

The sequence is: **0**,1,10,11,**0**,5,14,15.

I know how to solve this kind of problems, but in this case the sequence repeats one number, 0.

I want to solve this like this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zce6NlHuvfs

But I don't how to manage the problem of the repetition of one number in the sequence.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keeping track of the preceding value is a potential solution.

Answer (score 6):

If you write down the mapping of count states 0-7 to outputs

```
count             oputput
C2 C1 C0          O3 O2 O1 O0
0  0  0           0  0  0  0    =  0
0  0  1           0  0  0  1    =  1
0  1  0           1  0  1  0    = 10
0  1  1           1  0  1  1    = 11 
1  0  0           0  0  0  0    =  0
1  0  1           0  1  0  1    =  5
1  1  0           1  1  1  0    = 14
1  1  1           1  1  1  1    = 15
```

You see that
O0 = C0
O1 = O3 = C1
O2 = (C0 OR C1) AND C2

So you can accomplish that simply with a 3 bit counter one OR and one AND gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhK9Qx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note: there is, however, a so-called [hazard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(logic)) between count state 5 and 6, 
i.e. there might be multiple edges before the signal settles to the new state. That won't be a problem if you don't care about output edges, only about levels.

Comment: This is good. +1!

Comment: Which software do you use to make that schematic?

Comment: @Josedearimatea He's using the schematic editor built into site.  See the pencil, diode, capacitor and resistor symbol at top of the Editor or type Ctrl-M while in Editor.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of making a counter that counts in a strange sequence, let the counter count normally, then map the result thru a lookup table.  It seems your numbers are limited to the 0-15 range, so 4 bits.  That means you only need a 4-bit memory with 4-bit addresses, for a total of 64 bits.

Even easier is to do this all in firmware in a microcontroller.  Generate the count by incrementing, then use the low 4 bits to index into a table.