# How to design a counter with an arbitrary sequence

Tags: digital-logic, design, flipflop

So there is many places where one can learn how to design a counter with an arbitrary sequence, but there seems to be a shortfall when it comes to arbitrary sequence when a number repeats...

I found the following link: [Design a Counter With an Arbitrary Sequence](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275653/design-a-counter-with-an-arbitrary-sequence)

[image]

Unfortunately my number is different. It has 2 numbers which repeat themselves.

But Im going to take a random number as I generally should be able to do this for any number, I believe.

Let me say my number is 8136367

The sequence would be 8,1,3,6,3,6,7 an then after 7 we would go back to 8.
3 and 6 repeats in this case.

I have done a table like the one in the other answer, unfortunately I dont know how to put it in here because it seems to make everything into one line....? 
but the point is that with that number I don't see a pattern forming anywhere. It is also mysterious to me how u can just see that O2 = (C0 + C1).C2, I mean, its not normal to just see that from the table. Its a completely random guess to me.

I want to know how I would design this counter if it has repeating numbers, using this way or any other way that I could use. I wanted to also use that video but it doesn't have a sequence where numbers repeat...

Thank you for help.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Harry Svensson I need to design a synchronous counter. The counter needs to produce a 4-bit digital output that represents the binary of digits that I have a sequence for, just like in the video.

Comment: "*the counter needs to produce a 4-bit digital output that represents the binary of digits that I have a sequence for*", this means nothing. But okay, if you don't want to answer properly. That's fine with me. - I'm just trying to find out if there is some other *correct* way to solve your *actual* problem that you still haven't shared. If it's just for curiosity, then so be it.

Comment: Since it is both combination and sequence dependent, a shift register must be used to store previous state. Thus choose JK , T or D FF then choose how to initialize and clock next state from register previous state and counter out.  Then minimize registers to 4 for synchronous race-free output.

Comment: I am not trying to be ambiguous here, I am literally trying to do what the video is doing. I am trying to output a number that I mentioned just like the in the video, but my sequence is different. I have to create the circuit for it with flip flops, and then also create VHDL for it... It has no other goal then to output those numbers in that sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Your task here is to identify how many states you need to count, not the numbers you need to output.

In your sequence 8,1,3,6,3,6,7 you actually have seven states. As such you need a counter that counts from 0 up to 6, and then translate those count numbers into the output values you desire.

You can do that with a bunch of simple logic gates for each bit of the output value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7LpTG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, a more flexible way is to use a normal counter and feed the outputs to the address bits of a ROM which then outputs the appropriate code for the count.

An additional data bits from the ROM is used to reset the counter.

The output latch runs off the opposite edge of the clock to keep everything synchronous.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNQhyu.png)</sup>

Comment: I doubt ill be able to use a ROM simply because I don't know what it is, but thank you for that diagram I will use that.

Comment: @Lukali ROM is a read only memory chip that needs to be preprogrammed with your desired output sequence.

Comment: @Lukali You will have a ROM available to you when you use VHDL. Which *appears* to be your end goal.